# In React-Router v5, how to access matched <Route>'s path outside of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In `react-router@5`, how I can access the matched `<Route>`'s `path` outside of it?

In my case, it's for a `<BottomNavigation>` that is rendered outside of the `<Switch>`. Code below:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <PublicRoute path={PATHS.AUTH} component={AuthPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path={PATHS.HOME} component={HomePage} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path={PATHS.EXPLORE} component={ExplorePage} />
          <ProtectedRoute path={PATHS.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute path={PATHS.PROFILE} component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
       {/* ⬇ requires access to any matched above <Route>s path ⬇ */}
        <BottomNavigation />
      </Layout>
    );
};
```

```
const BottomNavigation = () => {
  const username = useSelector(selectUserUsername);

  const history = useHistory();
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  const pathToPathname = {
    [PATHS.HOME]: '/',
    [PATHS.EXPLORE]: '/explore',
    [PATHS.PROFILE]: '/' + username,
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(pathToPathname[path]);

  // whenever client clicks on <BottomNavigationAction>
  const handleClick = (e, pathname) => {
    // without `value` prop, 2nd arg (`pathname`) returns the index of the clicked <BottomNavigationAction>
    setValue(pathname);
    history.push(pathname);
  };

  // whenever client navigates, update current <BottomNavigationAction> in UI
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(pathToPathname[path]);
  }, [path]);

  return (
    <MuiBottomNavigation
      value={value}
      onChange={handleClick}
    >
      <BottomNavigationAction icon={<FeedIcon />} value="/" />
      <BottomNavigationAction icon={<SearchIcon />} value="/explore" />
      <BottomNavigationAction icon={<UserAvatar />} value={'/' + username} />
    </MuiBottomNavigation>
  );
};
```

Comment: `useRouteMatch` is just a React hook, it can be used anywhere calling React hooks is valid. What exactly is the issue/question?

Comment: Hi. The question is, how can I access the `path` of the matched `<Route>`?

Comment: Are you just wanting to know what the currently matched path is? What do you need to do with this information? Can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] for what you are wanting or trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I've included the code for what I'm trying to achieve already. And yes, in effect, I want to know what the currently matched `path` is

Comment: Are `"/home"` (*or just `"/"`?*), `"/explore"`, and `"/:username"` the only paths you care about checking if they are matched/active? If you passed an array of paths you want to test to the `useRouteMatch` hook would this be sufficient for your use case?

Comment: Yes, I only want to check those paths. I imagine that would be sufficient, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you just want to test if the current matched path is one of `PATHS.HOME` (*`"/"`*), `PATHS.EXPLORE` (*`"/explore"`*), or `PATHS.PROFILE` (*`"/:username"`*). You can pass these in an array to the `useRouteMatch` hook. Keep in mind that similar to the `Switch` component that path order and specificity still matters. Order the paths in inverse order of path specificity. The home `"/"` should come *after* all other more specific paths.

```js
const { path } = useRouteMatch([PATHS.EXPLORE, PATHS.PROFILE, PATHS.HOME]);
```

[image: Edit in-react-router-v5-how-to-access-matched-routes-path-outside-of-it]

If you need finer-grained control over the matching you can specify a match object instead.

```js
const { path } = useRouteMatch({
  path: [PATHS.HOME, PATHS.EXPLORE, PATHS.PROFILE],
  exact: true,
  ...strict, sensitive, etc...
});
```

For more details, see:

- [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)
- [`matchPath`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath/props)

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the assistance. I've just tried this and `path` returns `'/'` irrespective of the matched <Route>. Is this not because `<BottomNavigation>` that is calling `useRouteMatch` is outside  of the matched `<Route>`?

Comment: @AlexT Ah, yeah, perhaps. I'm away from a computer but will check/test and update you.

Comment: @AlexT It was the old classic route path specificity issue at play. The home `"/"` was the first path in the array and it matches all paths, so it's OFC returned.

Comment: Thanks, almost there! Sadly `'/explore'` is matching with `PATHS.PROFILE` which returns `'/:username'`. Anything I can do to remedy this?

Comment: @AlexT This doesn't appear to be the case in the sandbox I linked (*for me at least*). If it's not too much trouble do you mind either forking my sandbox or creating one of your own with more of your actual code that reproduces the issue that we could take a look at live?

Comment: Just realised my `PATH.EXPLORE` was to something else haha! Problem solved. Thanks for your assistance :)

Comment: @AlexT Ah, ok, yeah, that might cause a path matching issue.  Glad it's working for you now. Cheers and good luck!